# iOS Simulator is opened but failed to connect to Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter

I am trying to run my code on a MacBook. I have installed FVM to manage my Flutter versions. I also have completed all steps successfully. In the case of Flutter pre-defined code When I open the ios simulator (iPhone 15 pro max) it is linked properly with my vs code but when I open my own app code, and tries to open the simulator with ctrl + shift + p it starts loading and this simulator does not show in the vs code.
One thing you need to note, fvm version is 3.10.0 the output of flutter doctor -v

```
✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.2, on macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-x64, locale en-AE)
• Flutter version 3.16.2 on channel stable at /Users/admin/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 9e1c857886 (7 days ago), 2023-11-30 11:51:18 -0600
• Engine revision cf7a9d0800
• Dart version 3.2.2
• DevTools version 2.28.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A507
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.78.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • 9D39AA41-635D-4CF1-B93F-3018A858A8AD • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.199

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

With this output, you can see, that simulators are installed. Can you suggest me what to do?